# How to bind a combo box with a List of string within another List of objects

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-store-apps

Windows store App 8.1 : How to bind a combo box with a List of string within another List of objects, is this possible?

Here is what i am trying.

```
 public class CompanyContact
    {    

            public int ContactId { get; set; }   

            public string Name { get; set; }    

            public List<string> EmailAddress { get; set; }    

    }

 private Company _selectedCompany;
        public CompanyContact SelectedCompany
        {
            get { return _selectedCompany; }
            private set
            {
                _selectedCompany= value;

            }
        }

private IEnumerable<CompanyContact> _companyContact;
 public IEnumerable<CompanyContact> CompanyContacts
        {
            get { return _companyContact; }
            set
            {
                _companyContact= value;
            }
        }
```

Here is the XAMl that uses it

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" MinWidth="500" ItemsSource="{Binding CompanyContacts, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                    PlaceholderText="Select" DisplayMemberPath="EmailAddress" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCompany, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

1. How do i display all the emails for all company's contact in the dropdown
2. Once one email is selected i need the company object that holds the email or the Contactid for the selected email.

What will be the best approach above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set DisplayMemberPath="EmailAddress" but your EmailAddress property is a List. I would create a new get only string property like DisplayEmailAddresses that joins the items in the EmailAddress List and use that as DisplayMemberPath.

This is assuming you want a combobox that has one line for each CompanyContact and displays only their email addresses.

Comment: This would require to create a new List of object that will hold emails and their contactid eg: Email1 - Contact1, Email2 - Contact1, Email2 - Contact2 or other information as well like Name and try to retrieve company object (this bit never worked not sure if it is store app issue, can select a single member eg: Name)

Comment: I'm confused as to what it is you're looking for now. From this comment it almost seems like you have a List of, lets say, 10 Companies that each have 2 EmailAddresses. You want a combobox that displays all 20 EmailAddress on a separate line? Would the user click an EmailAddress and then SelectedCompany is the parent of the EmailAdress?

Comment: yes to both. The only way forward i think will be to create new CompanyContact object for each emailaddress eg: CompanyContact1{Name: ABC,ContactId: 101, EmailAddress: one.abc@c1.com}, CompanyContact2{Name: ABC,ContactId: 101, EmailAddress: two.abc@c1.com}

Comment: Yes that would be a better approach. That way you could bind to your List of CompanyContacts with EmailAddress as the DisplayMemberPath. One more thing you should look at though: we know that a Company has more than one EmailAdress, but can an EmailAddress also be the contact for more than one Company?

Comment: Hopefully not :)  the second question is i have tried all possible ways but unable to retrieve an object eg: selectedCompany if the companyContact class now has string emailAddress

Comment: Your SelectedCompany property has a private set method, so presumably it can't be set from the View.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91518/discussion-between-gauls-and-alan-cortez).